# IOS API to get User name availability on Twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter

I want to access twitter from my iPhone app and want to check user name available or not..??? 
is there any API available to get the availability of User Name.

Akhzar Nazir

Answer (score 1):

Check if a `username` exists in Twitter or not.

This API returns valid info: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=testuser